# How to parse Json object to get root object from $type

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

Is there a way I can get the value as CustomerRecommendation from $type in the below Json so that I can use it to a matching DTO class in my own project for desrialization :

```
 var jsonToObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerRecommendation>(Json)
```

The reason for this is that the api root object varies based on certain conditons. Sometimes it is CustomerRecommendation and sometimes it is CustomerBase class. hence want to something like this

```
 type  = reqired type from Json
 var jsonToObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<type>(Json)
```

Json exampe

```
 {
"$id": "1",
"$type": "Customer.CustomerWeb.Common.CustomerRecommendation, Customer.CustomerWeb.Common.V4, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4",
"Addr1": "Cust1",
"CustomerAddress": {
    "$id": "41",
    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Customer.CustomerWeb.Common.CustomerAddress, Customer.CustomerWeb.Common.V4, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
    "Items": {
        "$id": "42",
        "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Customer.CustomerWeb.Common.CustomerAddress, Customer.CustomerWeb.Common.V4, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
        "$values": [
            {
                "$id": "43",
                "$type": "Customer.CustomerWeb.Common.CustomerAddress, Customer.CustomerWeb.Common.V4, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4",
                "CustomerID": 268541064,
                "ApplicationID": 110296837,
                "ProductID": 1,
                "ProductCode": 1,
                "Amount": 1000.00000,
                "AmountPercent": 2.98,
                "AppliedValueType": 1,                                   
                "Id": 811760147,
                "RealId": 811760147,
                "DirtyProperties": {
                    "$id": "46",
                    "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[Drive.Framework.DirtyProperty, OriginationFramework, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                },
                "IsDirty": false,
                "IsNew": false,
                "IsDeleted": false,
                "ModifiedDate": "2020-05-28T09:01:27.033",
                "CreatedDate": "2020-05-28T09:01:27.033",
                "ModifiedByID": 0,
                "CreatedByID": 0,
                "DeactivationDate": null,
                "ActivationDate": null,
                "SerializationTracking": null
            }
        ]
    },
    }
    }
```

Comment: Try `var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All }; var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, settings);`

Comment: I am getting the following error: Error resolving type specified in JSON 'CustomerWeb.Common.CustomerRecommendation, CustomerWeb.Common.Common.V4, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f291d57f641e84e4'. Path '$type', line 1, position 167

Comment: I forgot to mention the Json I am using is comming from a different project and the DTOS I am mapping them are having different namespace ad assembly to the Json class objects